# create object array based on max value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to create object array based on max value in javascript,
based on max value how to create object as shown

```
for(var i = 0; i<=max;i++){
  var result = [];
  result.push({id: `${i}`, name: `s${i}`});
  return result;
}


var max = 20;
var obj = [{id: 0, name: ""}]

Expected Output

result = [
  {id: 1, name: "s1"},
  {id: 2, name: "s2"},
  {id: 3, name: "s3"},
  ..  
  ..
  {id: 20, name: "s20"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you want to return a value you'll need a function. Then you'll have to take the initialization of the array out of the for loop, otherwise you'll be initializing it with every iteration. Then you can push the new objects to the array and finally you can return the newly populated array, like so:

```js
const createObjectArray = (max) => {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    result.push({ id: `${i}`, name: `s${i}` });
  }
  return result;
}

var max = 20;
let result = createObjectArray(max);

console.log(result);
```